# webpack-dev-server: npm error Windows_NT 7601

Tags: npm, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I have got the following error while I tried to command :

```
$ npm run dev
```

I have also used nodejs cmd, git and also having administritive privileges with the cmd.

Error is like following:

```
D:\IIT Samester\KAZ\ReactJSProjects\GitFrom\webpack-example-master\webpack-examp
le-master>npm run dev

> webpack-example@0.0.0 dev D:\IIT Samester\KAZ\ReactJSProjects\GitFrom\webpack-example-master\webpack-example-master
> webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build/

 70% 1/1 build modulesevents.js:85
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: listen EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1129:19)
at listen (net.js:1172:10)
at net.js:1270:9
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:81:16)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:99:10)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "node" "C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\b
in\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! webpack-example@0.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-example@0.0.0 dev script 'webpack-dev-server--devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build/'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the webpack-example package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build/
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls webpack-example
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\IIT Samester\KAZ\ReactJSProjects\GitFrom\webpack-example-master\
webpack-example-master\npm-debug.log

D:\IIT Samester\KAZ\ReactJSProjects\GitFrom\webpack-example-master\webpack-example-master>
```

Please do help to solve the issue.

Comment: The error says it's a webpack error (and not `npm`). Have you tried to simplify your code to see what's causing the error?

Comment: The source code collected frpm github is ok in another pc. But in my laptop I got the error. Don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I have solved the issue by self.

Its a problem on the port, nothing else.

I have other program that works on **port 8080**.

**webpack-dev-server** also wants to use that port by default.

So I have just change the port number **from 8080 to 8081** (can be anything valid other) in the ***ProjectFolder \node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js*** file.

**Anothe solution** is that you can stop that program working on port 8080.

Thank you :)

Comment: You should accept your own answer as, you know, answer

Comment: When I faced the problem, the solution was unknown and wrote in stackoverflow for getting help. After  solving the issue, I just post it for others.

Comment: I understand and thank you for that, and it’s better to accept your own answer if solved the problem